# JWT Token Security

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

As JWT tokens are sent over the headers to authenticate uses, a user can just inspect the web call in chrome dev tools and copy paste the token and use it to access the exposed API.

For example, if I am using this token to create a record, a malicious user can use the same token (by using the above mentioned way) to create a new record in Database.

How can I stop this from happening? Is using Token Encryption with public key of server the way to stop this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Several steps can be taken as given below:

1. You should use `https` connection instead of `http` connection. This will encrypt your message which is sent to server or received from server. So if a man in the middle catches your packet, he can't do anything because message is encrypted.
2. Also add a short time validity for `jwt token` depending your app behavior.
3. Add an appropriate key size for your self-signed token validation. `AES` keys shorter than 128 bits, or `RSA` keys shorter than 1024 bits for legacy apps.2048 bits encryption now a days popular.
4. [`HSM (Hardware Security Module)`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardware_security_module) can be introduce for signing and encryption task while key are not accessible from OS or software level.

You should be digging deep for more [here](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/JSON_Web_Token_(JWT)_Cheat_Sheet_for_Java)[cheat sheet for jwt token OWASP].

Answer (score 4):

Token represents user identity. It is normal, that user can view his own token.
Token is validated on the server. Normally there is is no easy way to fake a token. Use cannot generate a new token on his own.

Communication between browser and server should be done via TLS. Then no third party will be able to see the token.

If your user gives access to his browser to somebody else, then yes, the other person can potentially access the token and used it later on on another computer, it this token is not expired yet. But this is not specific to the token, this is like giving access to your password to smb else.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification on the point of giving access of browser to a user. I missed that point while thinking about JWT.